# Koa2 and History API fallback

Tags: koa2

I build SPA app, and I setup `history` mode in my router on frontend. I use Vue2.js - [here](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html) is problem describe only server configuration for Express.js, but I didn't know how to setup proper server configuration for my **Koa2 app**.

I take [connect-history-api-fallback](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback) middleware:

```
app.use(history());
```

but I got error:

```
TypeError: next is not a function
```

Then I use `koa2-history-api-fallback` module but didnt't work eather.

Is there any workaround, or any way to handle this problem.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`koa2-history-api-fallback` is an adapter for `connect-history-api-fallback` for Koa ^2.0.0. So basically using `koa2-history-api-fallback` should be the correct way.

This code should work:

```
const Koa = require('koa')
const app = new Koa();
const historyFallback = require('koa2-history-api-fallback')

app.use(historyFallback({
  index: '/index.html'
}))

app.listen(3000);
```

If you have any problems with this, can you provide your error messages?